# Shouldn't there be 6 fundamental forces?

Tags: forces, string-theory, standard-model, elementary-particles, beyond-the-standard-model

I'm listening to [Leonard Susskind's **The Black Hole War**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Hole_War).  In it he states (paraphrased) that a string wrapped around a compact dimension once imparts one unit of charge.  Wrapped one way, it's a positive charge.  If you wrap it the other way, it's a negative charge.  Wrapping it multiple times generates multiple units of charge.

Which got me to wondering.

We have 3 observable "normal" spatial + 1 time + 6 compact dimensions for 10 total dimensions.

If in [String Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory) wrapping a string around a *specific* compact dimension provides you with a unit charge, then shouldn't wrapping a string around other compact dimensions provide a unit involved in the other forces (unit mass, unit charge, quark number, lepton number, etc.)?

If true or plausible or at least not totally wonky, then that implies we ought to be looking for more forces along these lines.

I wonder if the properties of those wound strings tells us anything about those dimensions?  For example, since graviton & photon have no rest mass, perhaps their compact dimensions are smaller than those for the units involved in the weak & strong force.

By extension, that ought to be telling us that since we haven't discovered the 5th & 6th forces, either they are very weak (and so difficult to detect) or act over very small distances (and so difficult to detect).

**Shouldn't there be six fundamental forces - corresponding to the six compact dimensions called for by String Theory?**

Comment: Can you cite an experimental paper in which the six compact dimensions have been experimentally verified? Does Susskind tell you in the book about his attempts to build an experimental collaboration to get funding for such an experiment? If not... maybe that's a bit of a giveaway for how seriously one should take string "theory" at the moment. :-) On a more serious level, gravity is not a force, so that makes three. The electromagnetic and the weak force are really just one that splits below the electroweak scale where string theory doesn't do anything... how many fingers am I holding up?

Comment: Actually Susskind infrequently states that some of his use of String Theory is just as a useful model.  Some of which may never be testable (and yes I've read other books discussing M-theory et al and read some critiques of the untestability of these theories).  Still, makes for interesting thought experiments. :)

Comment: Physics doesn't run on thought experiments. It runs on real experiments. After over 40 years string theorists haven't been able to make a single testable prediction, so as a model it outright fails, even worse than supersymmetry, and that is bad enough. At least there is a bit of hope for that one with the latest LHC results... or not.

Comment: In the history, physics has made great progress through though experiments. This is not to advocate string theory in particular, just that we should not strip science into a mere cycle of performing and explaining real experiments.

Comment: If you don't like the definition of science as a continuous cycle of observation, hypothesis building and falsification trough experiments, there is always the philosophy department, where they are worshipping the "pure thought". When you are there, you can ask them how it comes that they can't even repair their own computers, let alone build them. Coming back to your question, it's not six vs. four because it's not even four. The usual count of four forces is based on a pretty poor and, to be frank, totally random understanding of how nature creates scales.

Comment: You *cannot* make deductions about what string theory does or does not say based on such popular accounts. And the four forces aren't all the same, and don't work with "charges" as you probably imagine it, so your conclusion of "looking for six forces" is not actually backed by any physics.

Comment: That's *almost* worthy of being the answer.

Comment: And as for experimentally verifying extra dimensions, in my work I frequently use imaginary numbers when performing complex calculus.  This math has no relation to physical world that I'm modeling and, therefore, it can't be experimentally verified.  However, this mathematical tool does produce the right answer and makes solving the problem much easier.  Since this doesn't meet your rigorous scientific standards, should I throw away this valuable and proven tool?